# Problem setting disabled prop and focus from the same function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build edit form fields. Here, you have to press a button before you can edit the form field. However, I'm having problems toggling the disabled prop and setting the focus of the element. This is some sample code. The input will only focus after I've clicked the button twice.

```
export default function App() {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);
  const inputEl = useRef(null);

  const onBlur = () => {
    setIsDisabled(true);
  };

  const handleEditClick = () => {
    setIsDisabled(false);
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Focus problem</h1>
      <h2>Focus only happens on the scond click!</h2>
      <input ref={inputEl} onBlur={onBlur} disabled={isDisabled} />
      <button onClick={() => handleEditClick()}>Can edit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-kare-6nxi7?file=/src/App.js:0-614)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting focus on a DOM element is a side-effect, it should be done within useEffect:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);
  const inputEl = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    inputEl.current.focus();
  }, [isDisabled]);

  const onBlur = () => {
    setIsDisabled(true);
  };

  const handleEditClick = () => {
    setIsDisabled(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Focus problem</h1>
      <h2>Focus only happens on the scond click!</h2>
      <input ref={inputEl} onBlur={onBlur} disabled={isDisabled} />
      <button onClick={() => handleEditClick()}>Can edit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works. Do you know why my solution didn't work? I've set the focus and had the component re-render after. I can't see any reason why it shouldn't work

Comment: This has to do with timing: calling ```setIsDisabled``` really just sets the value of a javascript variable, it needs to be applied to the DOM via a render, and then only you can call focus on the updated DOM input. All in all: you need a render between setIsDisabled and focus. Good info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks